# How can I find out what drivers are built into my kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel, sensors

`sensors-detect` tells me:

> To load everything that is needed, add this to `/etc/modules`:
>
> ```
> # Chip drivers
> coretemp
> w83627ehf
> ```
>
> If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
> contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

How can I find out which drivers are appropriate to skip, if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical method is to check your running kernel config, but this can be hard to parse because it will include both modules and other options and the names may not correspond:

```
grep "=y" /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

In practice, it's much easier to use either `find` or `locate`.

- Using `find` to search common locations:

  ```
  find /usr /lib /opt -type d -name modules -exec find {} -path "*`uname -r`*" -name "*.ko" \;
  ```
- Using `locate` to search your entire system:

  ```
  locate name-of-module | grep "`uname -r`.*ko"
  ```

  (If necessary, ensure database accuracy by first running `sudo updatedb`.)

If you see a `.ko` file entry like:

```
/lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
```

Then this module is *NOT* built-in and can be added to `/etc/modules`. If it's not found, it's either built-in or not present, and shouldn't be added.

A variation to find all non-built-in modules in `/lib/modules` is:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep -oP "(?<=/)\w+(?=\.ko)"
```